# Different IDE's different output?

Tags: c++, ide, compilation

I have the following problem : I write my code with the Qt IDE. I was informed that when people try to compile it with other IDE's (like codeblocks, or visual studio) The output they get is different and that there are maufunctions. Any ideas what can be causing this ? I will give you an example:

This is Newton's Method with a function who's root is 2.83something. I get the same, correct calulations each time I run it in Qt. I get "nan" in code blocks and something irrelevant as well in visual studio. I don't understand, do I have a mistake somewhere in my code ? What can be causing this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // we need the abs() function for this program

using namespace std;

const double EPS = 1e-10; // the "small enough" constant. global variable, because it is good programming style

double newton_theorem(double x)
{
    double old_x = x; // asign the value of the previous iteration
    double f_x1 = old_x*old_x - 8; // create the top side of the f(x[n+1] equation
    double f_x2 = 2 * old_x; // create the bottom side
    double new_x = old_x -  f_x1 / f_x2; // calculate f(x[n+1])
    //cout << new_x << endl; // remove the // from this line to see the result after each iteration
    if(abs(old_x - new_x) < EPS) // if the difference between the last and this iteration is insignificant, return the value as a correct answer;
    {
        return new_x;
    }
    else // if it isn't run the same function (with recursion YAY) with the latest iteration as a starting X;
    {
        newton_theorem(new_x);
    }
}// newton_theorem

int main()
{
    cout << "This program will find the root of the function f(x) = x * x - 8" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the value of X : ";
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    double root = newton_theorem(x);
    cout << "The approximate root of the function is: " << root << endl;

    return 0;
}//main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you run into *undefined behavior*:

```
if(abs(old_x - new_x) < EPS) // if the difference between the last and this iteration is insignificant, return the value as a correct answer;
{
    return new_x;
}
else // if it isn't run the same function (with recursion YAY) with the latest iteration as a starting X;
{
    /*return*/ newton_theorem(new_x); // <<--- HERE!
}
```

Missing a `return` on the `else` branch.

We could try to explain why Qt works (its compiler automatically puts the result of `newton_theorem` in the return registry, or shares registries, or whatever), but the fact of the matter is **anything can happen**. Some compilers might behave the same on subsequent runs, some might crash all the time.

Comment: Uhm... UB ? What is that ?

Comment: If I have a return in the else statement, it just prints out the retrun as a "root of the function". I have a decent idea of the problem now. Any idea how I  can fix this problem in particular ?

Comment: @Bloodcount nope, I didn't check any more of the code, this just popped out - it's definitely a problem - the rest you can solve by debugging.

Comment: Since I am doing it with recursion isn't it a must to not have a retrun unless a certain condition is met ?

Comment: @Bloodcount no, you **must** have returns on all paths. I have a feeling you don't understand how recursion works. For example, say I want to calculate the factorial. I'd write `int fact(int x) { if ( x==0 ) return 1; else return x*fact(x-1); }`.

Comment: Now I understand ! It was my understanding of recursion which was failing the program. Now I think I have a clear understanding of it. Thanks a lot !